# Change text and background color from a CEdit derived class

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a derived class from `CEdit` and I want to change the text and background color. I've tried with the messages `ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT` and `ON_WM_CTLCOLOR`, but I never receive these messages. Is there another option beside `ON_PAINT` ?

Here's how I initialize my `CColorEdit` control:

```cpp
//in my dialog.h
CColorEdit m_test;
//in .cpp
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_TEST, m_test);
```

I can't set the color manually like this :

```cpp
m_test.SetTextColor(...);
```

Here's how I've tried to handle `ON_WM_CTLCOLOR` :

```cpp
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CColorEdit, CEdit)
    ON_WM_CTLCOLOR()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

HBRUSH CColorEdit::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    HBRUSH hbr = CEdit::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
    if (m_theme != 0)
    {
        pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(0, 255, 0));
    }
    return hbr;
}
```

Here's my try with `WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT` :

```cpp
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CColorEdit, CEdit)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CColorEdit)
    ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT()
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CColorEdit::SetTextColor(COLORREF textColor)
{
    m_textColor = textColor;
    Invalidate();
}
void CColorEdit::SetBkColor(COLORREF backgroundColor)
{
    m_backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    m_brBkgnd.DeleteObject();
    m_brBkgnd.CreateSolidBrush(backgroundColor);
    Invalidate();
}

HBRUSH CColorEdit::CtlColor(CDC* pDC, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    pDC->SetBkColor(m_backgroundColor);
    pDC->SetTextColor(m_textColor);

    if (nCtlColor)       // To get rid of compiler warning
        nCtlColor += 0;

    return hbr;
}
```

Thx.

Comment: How about showing your handlers you have done so far? Can you be sure they are not being called?

Comment: https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/117/Q117778/

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I've put a breakpoint in OnCtlColor and I'm never going in the function. I've edited my question. I've tried the example in your link, and still doesn't catch the message.

Comment: Are you running in debug mode?  Release mode doesn’t always stop at breakpoints.

Comment: In the example the handler is added to the dialog and not the edit control. In the dialog handler it is passed the control so you know which you are working with. If it works I will add this as an answer.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Yes I'm running in Debug. I can't use the Dialog handler, I need to handle this in my CColorEdit class only.

Comment: Then maybe you have to do a owner drawn button. I don’t know. Sorry. Maybe someone else can help you.

Comment: `ON_WM_CTLCOLOR` is the wrong usage here. Show your attempt for `ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani just edited my questino with the attempt of ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT ! Thx :)

Comment: That should work fine. Maybe there is something else in your code that's blocking the message.

Comment: Pls add the C++ tag to your question, so it properly formats code.

Comment: Seems like you need both: http://glogoviak.blogspot.com/2008/08/change-background-color-in-cedit-mfc.html?m=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look [here](http://glogoviak.blogspot.com/2008/08/change-background-color-in-cedit-mfc.html?m=1). To quote:

> It was a real challenge for me to make a simple change of background color for `CEdit`. I was suprised to find out that there are no standard function, like `CEdit::SetBkColor`, to do this.

First step is to create class derived from `CEdit` and declare function `CtlColor`:

```
// CustomEdit.h
class CCustomEdit : public CEdit
{
protected:
  HBRUSH CtlColor(CDC *pDC, UINT);
  DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

Second, handle `WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT` event:

```
// CustomEdit.cpp
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CCustomEdit, CEdit)
  ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

HBRUSH CCustomEdit::CtlColor(CDC *pDC, UINT)
{
  COLORREF bkColor = RGB(255, 255, 255);
  pDC->SetBkColor(bkColor);
  return CreateSolidBrush(bkColor);
}
```

So you need to use **both** of them!

Comment: I've tried both example and nothing seems to work... Maybe one of my top class handles the OnCltColor message ? :/

Comment: @Emile Try doing a new test dialog project. Try to reproduce your error.

Comment: `::CreateSolidBrush(bkColor)` will create a brush handle each time. This handle is not freed and then lost, causing resource leak. You should create a class member data `CBrush m_brush;` and return that brush instead.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I had a base class that wasn't returning the CtlColor message ! Now that I changed that, it works perfectly ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you made the `CColorEdit` class only for performing this kind of custom color drawing, it wasn't needed, because you can simply process the `WM_CTLCOLOR` messages in the parent window. The message is actually `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` (`WM_CTLCOLOR` was used in old windows versions), however MFC maps all `WM_CTLCOLORxxxx` messages to the `ON_WM_CTLCOLOR` handler and passes the control-type as a paremeter.

Here is some code:

```
#define COLOR_YELLOW RGB(255,255,0)
HBRUSH hBrYellow = []() { return CreateSolidBrush(COLOR_YELLOW); }();

HBRUSH CMyDlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    // Our custom edit-control
    if (nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_EDIT && pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() == IDC_MYCUSTOMEDIT)
    {
        pDC->SetBkColor(COLOR_YELLOW);
        return hBrYellow;
    }

    // All the rest
    return CDialogEx::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
}
```

This code sample sets the background color of the edit-control to yellow. The edit-control is a simple and standard windows edit-box, no need for subclassing.

Comment: I have a lot of other classes who use CEdit, so I don't want to change that in every classes.. That's why I need to do the message handler in my CColorEdit class :/

Comment: That hBrYellow initialization is way over the top. You can just assign result of CreateSolidBrush to the variable. No need to flex with IIFE.